# How to simulate physical keyboard input

Tags: c#, winforms, keyboard, simulator, raw-input

I'm working with an C# Winforms project that read from multiple specified barcode scanner (app need to seperate data from scanner to have correct action)

I'm used raw input to filter by device ID and it works fine.

Now I want to develop a test app that simulate scanner (keyboard) input (to simulate daily working)

I've tried with some articles which tell me to use Windows API such as SendInput, SendMessage... but it's not contain real device ID (physical device ID), so my test app not recognized these input.

The Hid device ID look like that:
\??\HID#Vid_0536&Pid_01c1&MI_01#9&25ca5370&0&0000#{4d1e55b2-f16f-11cf-88cb-001111000030}

Is there anyway to simulate physical input device using C# and Winforms ? or send key to active app with physical (or fake) device ID ?

Thank you.

Comment: I always thought barcode scanners just output to the keyboard steam making them indistinguishable from regular keyboard input

Comment: Most of barcode scanner are simulate keyboard device, when you scan a barcode, it will sent data back to windows as keyboard input, so you can use hid device id to seperate them.

Answer (score 0):

We work with scanners to. If we scan, then we use a TextControl for our old WinForms programs. In that TextControl input can be selected by keyboard but also with any scanner. Sometimes you will need special scanner controls to accept that data, the scanner documentation tells you how to (add) send them with the barcode too.

So when a scanner sends its data to the TextControl the scanner also sends the 'Return' key for acceptance. And yes you can send additive keyboard input with Windows API to. If you use it that way then the technical sh1t of the scanner is decoupled because then its just an imput device for a TextControl and that can be anything as long as its recognized as an (usb) input device.

Comment: My app is a top-most, full screen app (like a game) there are no Textbox, user just scan barcode and app will recognize the data, to test the stability of app, I want to develop a test app to auto simulate user input activities.

Answer (score 0):

I've ended this issue by create a fake keyboard, set id, name,.. etc to nothing,
In raw input handler, I check key pressed, if there are no hardware ID, assume that is from fake ID and append fake device id to that message, now the simulator is working.
Thank you for support.